# How to simulate one step to a transfer function in python

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I've found `scipy.signal.dstep`, `scipy.signal.dlsim` functions that help simulate behavior of a transfer function, for example:

`signal.dlsim(signal.cont2discrete(([1], [1, 1]), 0.1), u=[1, 1], t=[0.0, 0.1])`

allows to model `1/(s+1)` function in `[0, 0.1]` time interval with control signal with value `1`.
But these functions do not allow to model just one step with initial values.

Are there any other functions that allow to model one step of a transfer function or how it's better to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, i'm not sure, if you want to use discrete time or continuous time, because you're using `s` operator for cont. time, the functions `dstep` and `dlsim` are used for discrete time representation. However, i used the continuous one in my example.

You can create a `dlti` object in python with `scipy.signal`'s `lti` function. The created filter object has a method `step` where the first parameter is used for the initial time vector. [lti.step](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lti.step.html#scipy.signal.lti.step)
So you can plot your step response with this snippet.

```
import scipy.signal as sig
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filt = sig.lti(1, (1,1))

plt.plot(*filt.step())
plt.plot(*filt.step(-1))
plt.show()
```

If you don't want to plot them, simply call

```
t, a = filt.step()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I meant that I need a function that gives me not a series of output values but just one. I mean that I can call it like `t1, y1, state1 = one_step(filt, state0)` and after `t2, y2, state2 = one_step(filt, state1)`

Comment: but anyway I found an answer: `_, yout, xout = signal.lsim(tf, U=[self_u, u], T=[0., .1], X0=x0)` and sequentially call it